# FCM notifications not always delivered after restoring internet connection

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated into our web app FCM notifications with FCM web push. Application is in testing phase and so far we have tested it on several Android and Windows devices with Chrome and Edge browser.

I have a service worker which registred when someone subscribe to push notifications. I can recieve notifications immediatly if device is online and connection is not interupted but the problem starts when for instance Android phone is not connected - after phone restores internet connection sometimes I receive all notifications sometimes nothing is received and sometimes partially - so totally random.

I can receive notifications in foreground where my code is:

```
    var firebaseConfig = {
                apiKey: "",
                authDomain: "",
                projectId: "",
                storageBucket: "",
                messagingSenderId: "",
                appId: ""
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

            fcmMessaging = firebase.messaging();

            fcmMessaging.onMessage((payload) => {
                    cuteToast({
                        type: 'success',
                        message: payload.notification.body,
                        timer: 5000
                    });
            });
```

I can receive notifications in background where my code (file is named:firebase-messaging-sw.js, after getting token service worker is registred and activated):

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-messaging-compat.js");

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

I am using predefined constants (title, body, icon) therefore I am not overriding onBackgroundMessage() as I leave it to default execution of push notification.

Notification are sent via PHP:

```
         $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

         $fields = json_encode(array ( 
            'registration_ids' => $tokens,
            'notification' => array (
                'title'=>$subject."-".date("H:i d.m.Y"),
                'body'=>br2nl($message,""),
                'icon'=>'/bug.png',
                'click_action'=>$clickUrl
            ),
            'data'=>array(
                'click_action'=>$clickUrl
            ),
            'priority'=>'high',
            'time_to_live'=>86400,
            'webpush'=>array(
                    'headers'=>array(
                        'TTL'=>86400,
                        'Urgency'=>'High'
                    )
            ),
            'android'=>array(
                'ttl'=>'86400s',
                'priority'=>'high'
            ),
            'apns'=>array(
                'header'=>array(
                    'apns-priority'=>10,
                    'apns-expiration'=>time() + 86400
                )
            )
        ));

        $headers = array (
                'Authorization: key=',
                'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $ch = curl_init ();
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

        $result = json_decode(curl_exec ( $ch ));

        curl_close ( $ch );
```

After sending notifications I always get success for all tokens so messages are delivered to FCM.

But the problem is that if the phone is off (locked, no internet connection etc) not every time that connection is restored all notifications are delivered - it looks like some are discarded or lost.

I am new to FCM so I can not find any information in firebase console where and why my notifications were not delivered.

I would be very thankfull if anyone know's what I am doing wrong and let me know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wiil be looking for an answer:

**notification** messages are considered collapsible by default so you will recieve only last one if client is offline when comming back online (doze mode). I could not find any option to make notification's non-collapsible.

Reference:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

> Except for notification messages, all messages are non-collapsible by
> default.

This means we have to remove notification payload from json so FCM will save old messages.

```
    $fields = json_encode(array ( 
            'registration_ids' => $tokens,
            'data'=>array(
                'messageTitle'=>$subject."-".date("H:i d.m.Y"),
                'messageBody'=>br2nl($message,""),
                'messageIcon'=>'/bug.png',
                'messageAction'=>$clickUrl
            ),
            'priority'=>'high',
            'time_to_live'=>86400
        ));
```

I intentionally changed title to messageTitle, etc. because on some phones we saw that if we use reserved key's like title, body, icon inside data phone treated message as notification and again some messages were lost. I did not find anything on that matter therefore I can not reference this.

After changing it I took care with onBackgroundMessage() method inside service worker to show "notification" which was previously handled by firebase automatically because of notification message type.

Also foreground method was changed to reference correct json fields.

Just to note we are using Firebase API for Javascript version 9 - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js

Hope this will help someone save few hours of research :)